# How to hide Mat Multi Select Dropdown on Clicking the custom Button

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

I am using Mat MultiSelect Dropdown When I am selecting the CheckBoxes
[image]

When I am clicking on Apply it stays shown until I click on somewhere else in the window.
How can I hide this dropdown on Click

Answer (score -1):

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" [ngClass]="{ 'hidden': "condition"}">
  <mat-label>Anything </mat-label>
```

.CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have asked about hiding the dropdown only when clicking on Apply

Comment: @HafizMuhammadAtif you can use this on your click event as well,